# How to get history of table structure change in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012. The table has few columns. Now I need to check for which column and what is the DDL script has been executed on this table. Or if it is possible to get what is the latest `ALTER` has been executed for this table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not already doing so, use souce control for your database and track the changes that way. Consider something like [DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which works in conjunction with source control providers.

Comment: I am maintaining source control. The actual problem is another team has executed the script wrongly and updated some at their own. Now need to look at what are the columns got altered and what are the altered script.

Comment: Redgate DLM, Schema auditing

Comment: @Arindam You cannot achieve this if you do not have a historical or archive table that store this data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot achieve this if you do not have a historical or archive table that store this data *(using a [DDL Trigger](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/))* or using a source control.

**OR**

You have to use a third-party log reader (if log is not shrinked) like [ApexSQL LOG](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! It's help us a lot